# What is the busiest airport in 2017?

Tags: airport, statistics

What is the busiest airport in the world, and how is this measured?

Comment: For what operations and for what period of time? The "busiest" changes daily, for example Wittman Regional becomes the busiest airport for about a week in July. O'Hare is historically the busiest, and Heathrow is often also cited as such.

Comment: @RonBeyer Well I left it kind of open ended so that multiple types of answers could be documented here. An answer could talk about the airport that on average has the most flights in and out per day or it could talk about Oshkosh.

Comment: In terms of passengers ? Flights ? Cargo volume/wheight ?
Anyway, you should at least try to use google. It's really not hard to find...

Comment: @Antzi Let's say number of flights in and out. To the rest of your comment, yeah I understand. I'm just new here and was trying to think of a quick question that might have some interesting discussions related to it (and to be honest, to get a little. It if Reputation so I can upvote some questions and answers and stuff. I understand the requirement to have reputation to do those things but for people who just want to participate it kinda forces them to come up with a quick question)

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. It's a little different around here.  You should have a read through the [help centre](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour), especially the parts about what's on topic and what kind of questions to ask. Questions are expected to be single, concrete enquiries to which specific concrete answers can be given. This is certainly not a place for discussion. You should edit you question to be more specific. Are you asking about aircraft movements, passengers, freight, runway utilisation or some other measure of "busiest"?

Comment: @Simon yeah sorry I'll just flag it for deletion.

Comment: As to "want to participate", nothing forces you to come up with a quick question. Rep is not a score. It is a loose measure of how much the community trusts you (the help centre explains this well). Do not try to chase it - it usually backfires.

Comment: I wouldn't delete it.  I would make it concrete by editing.  I don't think we have a duplicate for this question so it's a good one and with editing to make it specific, I can see no reason why it won't be a good question welcomed by the community.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the negativity... This is a question that has crossed many peoples minds and has a clear, objective answer. Yes there are a few ways to measure 'busiest' but come on, a good answer will easily explain the most common measurements and throw in a mention of Oshkosh for some trivia. Sometimes we act like a bunch of lawyers here!

Comment: @Ben Stack Exchange is different for a good reason and many of us like it for that.  There are many features to ensure that it is community driven.  The problem with this question is that there are not a few measures, there any many.  To illustrate.  Busiest all year round?  Busiest with seasonal variations?  Busiest GA or commercial?  Busiest by passengers or movements?  International or domestic?  Highest runway utilisation? Freight etc etc.  Add on to that, this year?  Last year?  Overall?  Moving average? If the question was "by international passengers", then it would be concrete.

Comment: @Ben As it stands, the only possible self contained answer would need to address all of those sub-questions, with references, and at best, would be incomplete.  This is not a good fit for the SE model.

Comment: Hope you don't mind - Ive narrowed this question to your first question (busiest airports) and completely removed the second (IMO, Ambiguous) question. That of course makes it match the answer I gave - feel free to rollback if you disagree. I suspect the accumulating close votes were due to the nature of the second question. The first was/is perfectly fine.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's been decades since Heathrow was the busiest by any of the primary measures. By movements, it's mostly been Atlanta in recent years, though it's gone back and forth some with O'Hare. By passengers, this will be Atlanta's 20th consecutive year. IIRC, it was O'Hare before that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note: Since this answer was first written, updated statistics have been published. The original answer was written against 2015 figures, with the update from 2017 figures.

---

There is no one simple measure of "busiest" when it comes to airports, there are usually (at least) three.

1. **Busiest by passenger traffic** - defined as total passengers emplaned and deplaned, with transit passengers counted once
2. **Busiest by cargo traffic** - loaded and unloaded freight and mail measured in metric tonnes
3. **Busiest by traffic movements** - total number of landings and takeoffs of all aircraft

---

The most recent statistics produced by [Airports Council International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_Council_International) are from 2017.

By **passenger traffic** the top 3 are

- 2015

1. Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airport,  USA
2. Beijing Capital International Airport,  China
3. Dubai International Airport,  UAE

- 2017

1. Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airport,  USA
2. Beijing Capital International Airport,  China
3. Dubai International Airport,  UAE

By **cargo traffic**

- 2015

1. Hong Kong International Airport, Hong Kong
2. Memphis International Airport, USA
3. Shanghai Pudong International Airport, China

- 2017

1. Hong Kong International Airport, Hong Kong
2. Memphis International Airport, USA
3. Shanghai Pudong International Airport, China

By **traffic movements**

- 2015

1. Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International Airport, USA
2. O'Hare International Airport, USA
3. Dallas/Fort Worth International Airport, USA

- 2017

1. Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International Airport, USA
2. O'Hare International Airport, USA
3. Los Angeles International Airport, USA

*<sub>(Aside: Wow, those Americans like their traffic movements - 8 of the top 10 are USA! | 2017 update: 7/10)</sub>*

---

There are a few non-standard claims too. They are interesting, if not winners.

- Memphis International is the [Home of FedEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FedEx), and as such was the highest freight airport for a number of years.
- [Gatwick Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatwick_Airport) is the busiest single-runway airport (There are actually two runways, but only one is ever in use)
- Wittman Airport hosts an [aviation event](http://www.eaa.org/en/airventure) which temporarily raises it to one of  the busiest airport in the world for that short period.
- The [airports of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_of_London) (Heathrow, Gatwick, City, Luton, Stanstead & Southend) host the most passengers annually for a single city's airports combined.

  *<sub>(Don't get me started on Southend being a "London" airport - it's at least 20 miles from what could sensibly be called London)</sub>*

---

References:

- [ACI: busiest airports in 2015](http://www.aci.aero/News/Releases/Most-Recent/2016/09/09/Airports-Council-International-releases-2015-World-Airport-Traffic-Report-The-busiest-become-busier-the-year-of-the-international-hub-airport)
- [ACI: busiest airports in 2017](https://aci.aero/news/2018/09/20/aci-world-publishes-annual-world-airport-traffic-report/)
- [Wikipedia: Busiest airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports)

Comment: technically Oxford is a London airport too - that's 60 odd miles out of the city!!

Comment: @Minnie oh gosh you're right! I even landed there a few weeks ago and never realised it was actually "London Oxford Airport". What's next? "London [Prestwick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Prestwick_Airport)" :)

Comment: Ironically, it's not mentioned in [Airports of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_of_London) so not counted in those figures. Aside: I missed City!

Comment: madness isnt't it! maybe they keep naming airports "london..." just to keep a hold of the crown you mentioned :)

Comment: @Minnie That's not only the case in London: in Germany we have Frankfurt (FRA) but the airport mainly used by low-cost carriers (like Ryanair) is officially called “Frankfurt-Hahn” (HHN) – albeit it's 110 km (70 miles) away and not even located in the same federal state! As a native Frankfurter (no, not the sausage) this always bugs me a bit. ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck yes but in London we have; Luton (Bedfordshire), Stanstead (Essex), Gatwick (West Sussex) and Southend (Essex). Only Heathrow (barely) and City (very much so) are actually *in* London.

Comment: Yeah, the list of airports by cargo is kind of funny, particularly the difference between the U.S. and non-U.S. cities on the list. One expects to see huge cities like Hong Kong (#1), Shanghai (#3), Seoul (#5), Dubai (#6), Tokyo (#8), Frankfurt (#9), and Taipei (#10). Memphis, Tennessee (#2, within about 3% of #1) is probably less expected for most people, let alone Anchorage, Alaska at #4 and Louisville, Kentucky at #7.

Comment: @reirab Louisville is explained by [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldport_%28UPS_air_hub%29). And everyone uses ANC as a cargo hub, which makes more sense when you remember the earth isn't flat and fuel is usually cheaper in the US.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Right, it makes sense when you know the reasons behind it, it's just kind of amusing and probably not what most people would think if they didn't know the background. ANC is also used a lot as a refueling point for trans-Pac flights that don't want to (or can't) carry a large enough fuel load to make the entire trans-Pac flight directly. Even lots of passenger flights used to refuel there back before passenger airplanes commonly had enough fuel capacity to make trans-Pac jumps directly.

Answer (score 1):

Atlanta airport (KATL) in the USA is the busiest airport in the world measured by passenger traffic.

Gatwick airport (EGKK) in England is the busiest single runway airport in the world, meaning that their runway is probably the busiest runway you will find anywhere.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports).

Answer (score 0):

This CNN article just reported on 2017's busiest airports.

https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/worlds-busiest-airports-2017/index.html

> Worldwide passenger traffic increased 7.5% to 8.3 billion in 2017, one of the strongest growth rates on record.
>   International passenger numbers were up 8.6% globally.
>   Worldwide cargo traffic rose 7.7%. The world's largest air cargo hub remains Hong Kong. The US city of Memphis, Tennessee, took the second spot, followed by Shanghai, China.
>   Worldwide aircraft movements increased 3% in 2017 to 95.8 million
>
> The world's busiest airports 2017
>
> 1. Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International Airport (Georgia) -- 104 million passengers
> 2. Beijing Capital International Airport (China) -- 96 million
> 3. Dubai International Airport (United Arab Emirates) -- 88 million
> 4. Tokyo Haneda International Airport (Japan) -- 85 million
> 5. Los Angeles International Airport (California) -- 84.6 million
> 6. Chicago's O'Hare International Airport (Illinois) -- 80 million
> 7. London Heathrow Airport (United Kingdom) -- 78 million
> 8. Hong Kong International Airport (China) -- 73 million
> 9. Shanghai Pudong International Airport (China) -- 70 million
> 10. Aéroport de Paris-Charles de Gaulle (France) -- 69 million
> 11. Amsterdam Airport Schiphol (Netherlands) -- 68.5 million
> 12. Dallas/Fort Worth International Airport (Texas) -- 67 million
> 13. Guangzhou Bai Yun International Airport (China) -- 66 million
> 14. Frankfurt Am Main Airport (Germany) -- 64.5 million
> 15. Atatürk International Airport (Turkey) -- 64 million
> 16. Indira Gandhi International Airport (India) -- 63.5 million
> 17. Soekarno-Hatta International Airport (Indonesia) -- 63 million
> 18. Singapore Changi Airport (Singapore) -- 62.22 million
> 19. Incheon International Airport (South Korea) -- 62.16 million
> 20. Denver International Airport (Colorado) -- 61 million

Comment: Note this can only be based on preliminary figures - https://aci.aero/news/2018/04/09/aci-world-releases-preliminary-2017-world-airport-traffic-rankings-passenger-traffic-indian-and-chinese-airports-major-contributors-to-growth-air-cargo-volumes-surge-at-major-hubs-as-trade-wars-thre/ The final report for 2017 will probably be released in the next few weeks based on the timescale of the 2015 figures (released September 2016)

Comment: That's a lot of people going somewhere else!

Comment: Why the downvote?